# pdfpages + hyperref : hyperlinks in list of tables pointing wrongly to first page of document

Tags: tables, hyperref, lists, pdfpages

- In the TOC, the hyperlinks are pointing correctly to the pdf document included with pdfpages
- But, in the lists of tables / figures, the hyperlinks are pointing wrongly to the cover page of my document (a book), instead of pointing to the included pdf document.
- I compile in pdflatex

Does anybody know how to fix that problem ?

```
    \includepdf[pages={1},scale=0.9,landscape=false,turn=true,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}},addtotoc={1,section,2,heading-toc,label-toc},  
     % addtotoc={⟨page number⟩,⟨section⟩, ⟨level⟩,⟨heading⟩,⟨label⟩}
     addtolist={1,figure,heading-tof,label-tof}  % addtolist={⟨page number⟩,⟨type⟩,⟨heading⟩,⟨label⟩}
     ]{file.pdf}

    \includepdfmerge[nup=1x3,scale=0.9,column=true,frame=true,angle=90,delta=0 0,offset= 0 0,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}},
    addtotoc={1,subsubsection,2,heading-toc,label-tdm},
    addtolist={1,table,heading-tot,label-tof}]
                   {file1.pdf, file2.pdf, file3.pdf}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: In fact, if I have a simple document, everything is working fine. My main LATEX document has lots of packages / macros / included pdf documents, hence is not slim enough to be put on the website.

Comment: I suspect that something is blocking the hyperlinks from going backwards from the Tables of tables / figures to the targeted tables / figures. At first, I had the same problem with the Table of contents --> I put systematically a \cleardoublepage\newpage before each part / chapter / section --> it cleared the way for the hyperlinks of the Table of contents to go forward precisely. Would there be something to do to clear the way "backwards" ?

Comment: - The problems with  the Table of contents were caused by an error in the number of arguments of one macro containing an \includepdf --> that is why the \cleardoublepage/newpage stopped the error from propagating throughout the document.

Comment: - The links in the TOF are working fine for \begin{figure}\includegraphics... but not for \includepdf for which the links go to the very first page of the document ... Strange behavior

Comment: Did you compile several times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packages "float" and "rotfloat" were blocking the proper functioning of the hyperlinks -->  taking them out solved the problem.